# Python unittest at command line, resolving dependencies

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have to use python 2.6.6 for a project. I built it using PyCharm on Windows. In PyCharm, I can execute my test file, and it runs correctly. `merge_sort_test`:

```
import unittest
from merge_sort.merge_sort import get_middle, merge, merge_sort

class MergeSortTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def testGetMiddle_5_shouldBe2(self):

...

def main():
    unittest.main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The folder structure is:

```
merge_sort
|__ __init__.py
|__ merge_sort.py
|__ test
   |__ __init__.py
   |__ merge_sort_test.py
```

I need to be able to run tests from a command line (in Windows and Unix), as well as within PyCharm.

However, I am not sure how to execute the test from the command line with correctly resolved dependencies.

If I execute the test file from `merge_sort/test`, with `python merge_sort_test.py`, I get the message `No module named merge_sort.merge_sort`.

[EDIT]Also, I need a way to do this without setting environment variables, as other people will need to be able to download and run the code as-is.[/EDIT]

I have looked around StackOverflow for other ways to execute the test at the command line, without success. Some of them just don't work (at least with v2.6.6), but some of them I didn't understand. I am looking for an explanation of how to execute tests that can be understood by a Python novice.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your python path in your shell environment to add these file paths,

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/merge_sort_folder
```

and if i am not wrong, python needs a `__init__.py` in the location, `/path/to/merge_sort_folder` to treat as an importable module

and then run your tests

Comment: When running the line you suggest I get `Bad : modifier in $ (/)`. I believe you are correct about needing `__init__.py`. Those files are present

Comment: Also, could you explain what the line `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/merge_sort_folder` is supposed to do, please?

Comment: if you are in bash shell on a linux, do `man export`. if you are in windows, i donno... You need to substitute your path in the place of `/path/to/merge_sort_folder`

Comment: Could you, please, add some detail to your answer? I am not able to use what is there to solve my issue